# hosting web service in IIS, getting "The resource is not found" RSS

Tags: asp.net

I added a web service to the IIS and I get the following message:

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
 Requested URL: /MyWebService/datasynch.asmx

In the IIS, I did theo following steps:

1. Application Pool is set at .NET Framework v2.0.50727, Intregrated Managed pipeline mode
2. Authenication: On Anonymous Authentication is enabled
3. Binding htp:*.:82
4. I set the physical path to the WebService folder ie C:\Project\MyWebService

Comment: Should it not just be `http://serveraddress:82/datasynch.asmx`? Also, I think you can only browse ASMX directly from the `localhost` of the service

Comment: If you (just for a minute) turn on directory browsing for that folder, do you see any of your files?